# Reading Serial Data for 1 second in Raspberry Pi using 'stty'

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi

I am trying to read data from a serial port on Raspberry Pi using the **stty** command like this.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200 min 0 time 10
cat < /dev/ttyACM0
```

What I'm expecting is that the **cat** command will read data only for 1s (referring to the man page of **stty**). But the **cat** command is reading data continuously. How can I read data only for 1 second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself solved it after multiple attempts. I am posting the answer as it might help someone.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200 -xcase -icanon min 0 time 10
cat < /dev/ttyACM0
```

The timeout is **N tenths of a second**. So if you want to read data for **N** seconds set timeout to **N*10** seconds

Comment: Not that it is critical, but adding the Pi model you are using would provide a bit more complete picture. 3, 3+, 4, or 2, etc..

Comment: It will work for any computers with **stty** command installed and with working serial ports.